# Firebase undefined is not an object when opening an array

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

So this is really strange

this is my code when it works

```
useEffect(() => {
        // Alleen preview
           async function getTracksData() {
                let TrackData = await firebase
                    .firestore()
                    .collection('TrackScreen')
                    .doc('LeerjarenData')
                    .get();
                if (!TrackData.exists) {
                    console.log('Geen data')
                } else {
                    let TrackDatav2 = TrackData.data();
                    setTrackScreenData(TrackDatav2) 
                }
           } getTracksData()
            // SNAPSHOT USER DATA
            db.collection("users").doc(currentUserUID)
                .onSnapshot((doc) => {
                    setUserData(doc.data());
                });
    }, [])

    console.log(trackscreenData.data)
```

this works perfectly but when i change my console to

```
console.log(trackscreenData.data[0]
```

it gives me this error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'trackscreenData.data[0]')
```

then when i change my console again to

```
console.log(trackscreenData.data)
```

it works and when i change i back to

```
console.log(trackscreenData.data[0])
```

and save the changes it gives me the data i want

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you are trying to use the data from your asynchronous call before its ready.

To handle the case where your data hasn't finished loading, you should use:

```
console.log(trackscreenData && trackscreenData.data)
```

---

Based on the patterns in your code, you have these lines at the top of your component.

```js
const { currentUserID } = useAuth(); // or similar

const [userData, setUserData] = useState();

const [trackscreenData, setTrackScreenData] = useState();
// NOTE: check for typos: "trackscreenData" !== "trackScreenData"
```

On the **first render** of your code, `trackscreenData` will be `undefined` because you haven't passed an initial state into the `useState()` method.

```js
const [trackscreenData, setTrackScreenData] = useState(/* initial state */);
```

```js
// `trackscreenData` initially set to `null`
const [trackscreenData, getTracksData] = useState(null);

// `trackscreenData` initially set to `[]`
const [trackscreenData, getTracksData] = useState([]);

// `trackscreenData` initially set to the result of the function,
// an array containing the elements 0 through 99. The function is
// only executed once to set the first value.
// trackscreenData = [0, 1, 2, 3, ... , 97, 98, 99];
const [trackscreenData, getTracksData] = useState(() => {
  Array.from({length: 100})
    .map((_, i) => i);
}
```

When React executes your code, any calls to setters returned from `useState` calls (e.g. `setTrackScreenData`) are **queued**. Only once your code has finished executing, are they evaluated and any new renders triggered.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0); // `count` is initially set to `0`

useEffect(() => {
  if (count < 10) {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }
})

console.log(count);

console.log("rendered");

// Console logs:
// > "0"
// > "rendered"
// > "1"
// > "rendered"
// > ...
// > "9"
// > "rendered"
// > "10"
// > "rendered"
```

Your fetch of user data should be in its own `useEffect` call and should return its unsubscribe function:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!currentUserUID) {
    setUserData(null); // user not signed in
    return;
  }

  // SNAPSHOT USER DATA
  return db.collection("users") // <- note the return here
    .doc(currentUserUID)
    .onSnapshot((doc) => {
      setUserData(doc.data());
    });
}, [currentUserUID]);
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let disposed = false;

  // Alleen preview
  async function getTracksData() {
    let TrackData = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('TrackScreen')
      .doc('LeerjarenData')
      .get();

    if (disposed) return; // component was removed, do nothing

    if (!TrackData.exists) {
      console.log('Geen data')
    } else {
      let TrackDatav2 = TrackData.data();
      setTrackScreenData(TrackDatav2) 
    }
  }

  getTracksData()
    .catch((err) => console.error(err)); // don't forget to handle errors!

  return () => disposed = true; // ignore result if component disposed
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the document ID by `.doc(...)` and hence you are getting a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) as the response which is not an array.

If you were using queries like `.where(...)` then it would have returned a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot).

> A QuerySnapshot contains zero or more DocumentSnapshot objects
> representing the results of a query. The documents can be accessed as
> an array via the docs property or enumerated using the forEach method.
> The number of documents can be determined via the empty and size
> properties.

So if you are fetching only a single document that way, you don't need to access the doc by `[0]` as it is not an array. You can simply access the data by `dataSnapshot.data()`

Although I can't see where is `trackscreenData` defined?

```
useEffect(() => {
        // Alleen preview
           async function getTracksData() {
                let TrackData = await firebase
                    .firestore()
                    .collection('TrackScreen')
                    .doc('LeerjarenData')
                    .get();
                if (!TrackData.exists) {
                    console.log('Geen data')
                } else {
                    let TrackDatav2 = TrackData.data();
                    setTrackScreenData(TrackDatav2) 
                    console.log(trackScreenData)
                }
           } 
    }, [])
```

Comment: i have tried it but it doesn't work for me there was a wrong console in my question. i now have changed it

Comment: @SandervanMaastricht please try copying my code above